# setting up a custom icon for a marker in JxMap

Tags: java, jxmaps

I am evaluating JxMaps library. 
I cannot set a new icon to a marker.

```
Marker marker = new Marker(map);
marker.setPosition(new LatLng(39.833851, -74.871826));
ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/flag.png"));
marker.setIcon(newIcon);
```

My problem is that *marker.setIcon* method does not accept ImageIcon      attribute but String.
How can I change it a default icon ?

Here is a link to APIs:
https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxmaps/docs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are passing string to Marker.setIcon method, you should provide URL to resource that contains desired image.

But, alternatively, you can pass reference to Icon object. This object have methods to load images. For example:

```
Icon icon = new Icon();
icon.loadFromStream(PlacesSearchExample.class.getResourceAsStream("res/test.png"), "png");
marker.setIcon(icon);
```